# TwinCAT 3 or IntervalZero

Tags: twincat, rtx, ethercat

I intend to test EtherCAT communication for a new board (assume the name is XYZ). So I plan to make XYZ as the Slave and connect to a master. To make life easier for me, I decided to go with TwinCAT 3 or RTX64 as the Master on my own PC (with Windows and quad-core xeon cpu). 3 questions. 
 1. Which one of these softwares is better and why? Example -In terms of modularity, further projects, compatibility (both software and hardware), matlab integration, costs (unforeseen too) and so on (can be more than what I mentioned).
 2. Can I configure an EtherCAT master using the software to send data over the  existing Ethernet port of the PC.(I did read that they both support primarily on Intel chipset but confirming).
 3. The XYZ Slave is non-intel EtherCAT slave chipset. Will this create complications? (Ideally it shouldn't be a problem because these software tools must help more than just Intel right, but confirming)

Answer (score 0):

1. Both are real time but twincat is more used so you woould have more help if you're lost somehow.
2. EtherCAT is just another protocol from ethernet. with twincat you will be able to reach your ethercat slave from your PC. (if what I understood about your question was right)
3. You should not have problem because Ethercat is a protocol with strong matter design, not like CanOpen for example where you can find multiple declination of the protocol.

If it helps. Have a nice day.

Comment: Thank you. Question 2 - I read that TwinCAT supports only Ethernet chipsets made by Intel. [link](http://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=content/1033/tcsystemmanager/reference/ethercat/html/ethercat_supnetworkcontroller.htm). But what I don't understand from this is whether I can still emulate EtherCAT protocol (using a non-Intel Ethernet card) to communicate to non-Intel EtherCAT slaves (XYZ boards that support EtherCAT). If the answer is yes, I can, then can I still achieve real time characteristics (I need to meet real time deadlines).

Comment: Under Attention you should have your answer.               http://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/fc900x/html/fc900x_tc-etherprotactivate.htm&id=

Comment: Thanks a ton :) Missed that detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an external EtherCAT master board such as this one. 
http://radictech.com/ftp53_boards/LZ100_flyer.pdf

It works with KPA Studio to give you full EtherCAT instrumentation and ability to control and interrogate you slave device.
https://koenig-pa.de/?dl_name=https://koenig-pa.de/pdf/kpa_ethercat_studio_flyer_15_1.pdf

The master runs independent of the PC so you don't have to worry about the drivers. It can scan the network at sub 100us cycles.